# Vue.component is not a function / Migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3 Version

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am trying to update the Vue version in a project from 2 to 3. The thing is, that I have to use .js files, no .vue. The problem is, that I cannot find a substitution for "Vue.component".

My app.js

```
    // Vue Router 4
    var router = VueRouter.createRouter({
        history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
        routes,
      });

    // Create Vuex store
    var store = Vuex.createStore({
        state: {
            // state 
        }
    });

    // Vue 3
    var app = Vue.createApp({});

    app.use(router);
    app.use(store);
    app.mount('#app');
```

One of the components:

component-ex.js

```
Vue.component('component-ex', {});

// I also tried app.component('component-ex', {});
```

Then I import the app and all components via index.html

Index.html

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.0/dist/vuex.global.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="/components/component-ex.js"></script>
```

In the version 2 everything worked but now it throws an error: Vue.component is not a function

Comment: Because there's no `Vue`. You already use app for app.use. Why not for anything else?

Comment: When I use app.component, the error is thrown Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

Comment: It's defined where you defined it, `var app =`. If you need to use it in another place, you need to export and import it. You will naturally have problems when using non-modular JS in Vue 3. Consider using native ES modules <script module>, or you'll have to share `app` through globals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#mounting-the-app):

*The .mount() method should always be called after all app configurations and asset registrations are done. Also note that its return value, unlike the asset registration methods, is the root component instance instead of the application instance.*

So your index.html should probably look more like this:

```html
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.0/dist/vuex.global.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="/components/component-ex.js"></script>
    <script src="/components/another-component.js"></script>
    <script src="/components/yet-another-component.js"></script>
    
    <script>app.mount('#app');</script>
```